Can I combine a line initializing an array with a for loop?
I'm very new to Kotlin and programming in general, and have this line of code:
val arr1 = IntArray(100)

val arr2  = IntArray(5)

for (i in arr1){ arr2[(arr1[i] / 20)]++ }

arr2 is supposed to be used to determine ranges of values (by 20s) that are going to be stored in arr1. It will then be used to print out a char of the user's input based on how many values in arr1 fall into that range with a for loop line like so:
for(j in 0 until counter[x]) {print(inChar)

I was wondering if there was a way to simplify the declaration of arr2 and the for loop into a single line of code, or to where I didn't even need to declare arr2 at all? My code currently works the way I have it, but I'm all for being efficient and keeping the number of lines I use to a minimum if at all possible. I've researched lambda expressions, but I don't know if those would actually help in this case at all.

Did you omit code where you fill arr1 with data? Because if not, it’s all zeros. Either way it doesn’t make sense to iterate the values of an array and use those values as indices into the same array. So, it’s hard to tell what your for loop is trying to accomplish.

Can you better explain what arr2 need to contain?

What is counter and what is x in your second code block?

Let's see if I understand your question correct.
I assume that your array arr1 contains 100 values between 0 and 100 (exclusive), i.e. in the interval [0,100).
What you want is to group the values by intervals [0, 20), [20, 40), [40, 60), [60, 80), [80, 100).
Then for each interval I and the number X of values in arr1 that are in that interval I, you want to print a given character X times.
That can be achieved like this:
arr1.groupBy { it / 20 }.toSortedMap()
        .forEach { (_, values) -> println("$inChar".repeat(values.size)) }

The groupBy gives you a map that looks like this:
1=[25, 26, 38, 36, 38, 24, 28, 21, 22, 25, 31, 38, 31, 39, 28]
4=[85, 81, 89, 83, 91, 85, 94, 80, 97, 88, 90, 95, 92, 99, 88, 82, 85, 94, 80, 80, 92]
0=[6, 6, 10, 17, 13, 1, 19, 10, 1, 6, 6, 15, 2, 19, 9, 18, 2, 17, 13, 3, 8, 17, 15, 6, 19, 17, 15, 5, 17, 11, 14]
3=[74, 66, 72, 65, 76, 70, 69, 78, 60, 76, 76, 68, 61, 71, 61, 63]
2=[41, 53, 40, 58, 47, 41, 44, 58, 53, 59, 56, 59, 47, 59, 50, 55, 52]

The toSortedMap makes sure, all entries are sorted correctly:
0=[6, 6, 10, 17, 13, 1, 19, 10, 1, 6, 6, 15, 2, 19, 9, 18, 2, 17, 13, 3, 8, 17, 15, 6, 19, 17, 15, 5, 17, 11, 14]
1=[25, 26, 38, 36, 38, 24, 28, 21, 22, 25, 31, 38, 31, 39, 28]
2=[41, 53, 40, 58, 47, 41, 44, 58, 53, 59, 56, 59, 47, 59, 50, 55, 52]
3=[74, 66, 72, 65, 76, 70, 69, 78, 60, 76, 76, 68, 61, 71, 61, 63]
4=[85, 81, 89, 83, 91, 85, 94, 80, 97, 88, 90, 95, 92, 99, 88, 82, 85, 94, 80, 80, 92]

Then the forEach iterates over the entries of this map and writes the inChar character X times in a line, looking like this:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

